# Vagrant Up error on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, virtualbox

I've used virtual box and vagrant previously for a ruby on rails dev environment with the same configurations perfectly fine. I just upgraded to windows 10 and reinstalled vagrant along with virtual box. When I run the command

```
vagrant up
```

I get the following error.

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "C:/Users/canno/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20160714.0.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1469803400806_80416", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "6", "--disk", "C:\\Users\\canno\\VirtualBox VMs\\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1469803400806_80416\\box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting C:\Users\canno\.vagrant.d\boxes\ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64\20160714.0.0\virtualbox\box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\canno\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1469803400806_80416\box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_ERROR)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "enum RTEXITCODE __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct HandlerArg *)" at line 877 of file     VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Here is my vagrant file

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
  #   vb.gui = true
  #
    # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
    vb.memory = "2048"
  end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Define a Vagrant Push strategy for pushing to Atlas. Other push strategies
  # such as FTP and Heroku are also available. See the documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/push/atlas.html for more information.
  # config.push.define "atlas" do |push|
  #   push.app = "YOUR_ATLAS_USERNAME/YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME"
  # end

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline <<-SHELL
   #   sudo apt-get install apache2
  # SHELL
  config.vm.provision "shell", privileged: false, path: "provision.sh"

end
```

Here is my provision.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# Set up Scott's favorite prompt.
#
echo "export PS1='[\u@\h:\w]\n\$ '" >> ~/.bashrc

#
# Set up case-insensitive autocompletion.
#
echo "shopt -s nocaseglob" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "set completion-ignore-case On" > ~/.inputrc

#
# Install the requisite Ubuntu packages.
#
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install git libyaml-dev libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev nodejs-dev

#
# Install RVM.
#
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

#
# Use RVM to install the latest Ruby 2.2 release.
#
~/.rvm/bin/rvm --quiet-curl install ruby-2.2

#
# Make a symbolic link to the synced directory.
#
ln -s /vagrant ~/workspace
```

I have searched all over the internet for a solution to this problem but I have been unable to find anything that works. It does appear that this is a known issue that may have something to do with missing c++ files, but everything there I have tried hasn't worked either. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!